# Acces API-Gateway on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am using android studio to develop my mobile app, 
and I am currently able to upload and download the file from my S3 bucket
following [this guideline](https://grokonez.com/android/uploaddownload-files-images-amazon-s3-android), and now I would like to access to one of my api-gateway, this api-gateway is for invoke my lambda python function, and I also want my app to return back some useful information, how can I configure the above setup on my android studio, (I am using Android Studio 3.1.4, and my phone is running android 8.0)

Answer (score 0):

So using HttpUrlConnection you can use the following code to hit your api with a json body. With this we make post request and send json through that you give it.

```
public static String SendGet(String testevent, String testeventthing2) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("SENDGET");
    final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
    String url = "https://yourapiblah.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/";
    String json = "{\"testevent\":\"" + testevent + "\",\"testeventthing2\":\"" + testeventthing2 + "\"}";
    System.out.println("JSON: " + json);
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");

    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
    os.write(json.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    os.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    return String.valueOf(response);

}
```